# XML to Object Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, google-sheets

I'm trying to convert an XML response from Google to a custom object. My question is what's best to use as in `NSMutableArray` or `NSDictionary` when you have a multiple values in i.e. `<category>` or `<title>` and how to add them.

```
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006" 
          term="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#spreadsheet"/>
<title type="text">nothing</title>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marshaling XML onto a NSDictionary will work, however it can result in quite fragile and difficult to maintain code. Two reasons:

- It will result - 'magic strings' when requesting data. Any change in this string will propagate throughout the code-base.
- It will be difficult to read, and not exhibit the desirable self-documenting features of good OO.

Instead, its strongly recommended to map the XML of a service payload onto a use-case specific Objective-C object. This is aligned with the principle of *contract-first* development, meaning that any change to the service might only result in a change to this mapping onto the objective-C object.

A nice XML framework is [RaptureXML](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML)

Create a category on the RXMLElement class and extract the required information. Then to use the element, just:

```
RXMLElement* element = [RXMLElement elementWith. . . ];
MyDomesticCat* type = [element asCat];
```

Comment: This is actually pretty useful! I wished I could up-vote twice.

Answer (score 0):

Any XML is ideally a combination on dictionaries and arrays with its root tag initiating a single key dictionary. To take off the overhead of parsing xml to a customized object model you can use the nice framework, XMLReader, available at [github](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader).

If you use this framework, your xml parsing becomes as simple as:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:<# your xml data #> error:&err] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
//use dictionary
[dictionary release];
```

However, you need to pass some well formed xml data as its input. Also you might need to manipulate the content of the parsed dictionary, according to your needs.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at that! Edit: Although your answer mentions XMLDictionary, example says XMLReader. Are they the same?

Comment: @iwatakeshi I am extremely sorry that I pointed it out wrong. Yes you are right the class is XMLReader available from the following [link](http://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) at github. I have also edited my reply that points to the original framework now. Thanks for feedback :)